# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON

Tags: json

estoy haciendo un buscador en tiempo real que autocomplete algunos campos de un formulario.

Cuando muestro los datos por medio de un console.log() me funciona perfecto. Pero al momento de setear los campos me aparece el siguiente error

> VM787:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at Object.success (facturacionpos.view.php:180:41)
> at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:28294)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:29039)
> at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:79800)
> at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:82254)

La función debe ejecutarse por medio de un keyup.

Esta es la función

```
$('#codigo').keyup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var producto = $(this).val();
    var action = 'infoProducto';

    if (producto != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/papeleria/controllers/buscar.pro.controller.php',
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            
            data: {
                action: action,
                producto: producto
            },

            success: function(response) {

                if (response != 'error') {
                    var info = JSON.parse(response);

                    $('#producto').html(info.descripcion_);
                    $('#valor').html(info.valor_venta_);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Este es el código PHP donde está la consulta SQL

```
<?php
//buscar por código

include("/xampp/htdocs/papeleria/db.php");

    if(!empty($_POST)){

        if($_POST['action'] == 'infoProducto'){

            $producto = $_POST['producto'];

            $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT id_producto_, descripcion_, valor_venta_
                                                FROM productos_ 
                                                WHERE id_producto_ = $producto");

            $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if($result > 0){
                $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

                echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            }
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
?>
```

La búsqueda se realiza mediante el código del producto, el cual sólo contiene números, pero muestra el error aunque presione una tecla numérica, o cualquier otra.

Les agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Puedes incluir lo que contiene tu variable response?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Según el señor del tutorial (Sé que no es lo más recomendable ver tutoriales), contiene lo que viene en $data de la consulta SQL. Él lo tiene tal como lo tengo yo, y en el vídeo funcionaba.

Comment: Me refería al contenido del JSON. Así podemos emular lo que estas tratando de hacer

Comment: Perdón por no haber respondido antes, la verdad estoy demasiado agobiada. Mediante un alert response me muestra los siguientes datos, por ejemplo, si el código es 1 **response** contendría: **{"id_producto_":"1","descripcion_":"Archivador oficio primavera 13 bolsillos","valor_venta_":"18.500"}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé muy bien como lo logré, pero luego de poner un alert que me mostrara lo que contenía la variable response y que efectivamente me mostrara la información, intenté cambiar este .html

```
                $('#producto').html(info.descripcion_);
                $('#valor').html(info.valor_venta_);
```

Por un .val

```
                    $('#descripcion').val(info.descripcion_);
                    $('#venta').val(info.valor_venta_);
```

Me funcionó a la perfección.

Ahora mismo no sabría explicar exactamente qué era lo que causaba el error, pero espero que sea de ayuda si están pasando por lo mismo.